# Laptop doesn't stay asleep

Tags: suspend, power-management

I sleep my laptop at the end of the day. I do it with the power button, and it goes in to the 'deep' sleep state (`/sys/power/sleep` reads `s2idle [deep]`). From this point it requires hitting the power button - neither lid nor keyboard will wake it. This is what I want (as inactive as possible 'till the following day).

However by the morning the laptop is warm, often with the fans running, and the screen is turned on just by opening the lid. Something is waking the machine after sleep.

I've had a look at the log but can't see what the cause is.

Can anyone either see from the below journalctl extract what might be waking the machine (I think around 21:18?), or point me to resources to help me investigate? This is unviable, and I really don't want to shut the machine down every night.

Journalctl:

```
Mar 25 20:14:35 bamboo systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 25 20:14:35 bamboo systemd-sleep[28109]: Suspending system...
Mar 25 20:14:35 bamboo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.006 seconds
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: wlp59s0: deauthenticating from 10:b1:f8:b4:57:be by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVI
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: ACPI: EC: event blocked
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: IRQ 142: no longer affine to CPU2
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: IRQ 141: no longer affine to CPU3
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: IRQ 143: no longer affine to CPU4
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: IRQ 151: no longer affine to CPU4
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: IRQ 148: no longer affine to CPU5
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: IRQ 125: no longer affine to CPU7
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: IRQ 131: no longer affine to CPU7
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU8
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: IRQ 144: no longer affine to CPU8
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: IRQ 146: no longer affine to CPU8
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 8 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 9 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 10 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: ACPI: EC: EC started
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: intel_pstate: Disabling energy efficiency optimization
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU1 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU2 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU3 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x8
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU4 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0xa
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU5 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x1
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU6 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x3
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU7 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x5
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU8 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x7
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU9 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0x9
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU10 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0xb
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: CPU11 is up
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: usb 1-4: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: usb 1-12: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: usb 1-2: reset low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Mar 25 21:18:06 bamboo kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
```

Comment: Check your BIOS - is wake on LAN switched on?  If it is, try switching it off.

Comment: I'll add that to a list of experiments to try the next few nights.